# Which ItemControl should I choose and Why?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

I have an arbitrary count of ViewModels to display and I want that ViewModels to be displayed in two columns. The first column mostly should display a name/description and the content of the second column varies. I would prefer a `Grid`-like layout with a `Width = "auto"` for the first column and `Width = "*"`for the second column.

I tried a `ListView` with a `GridView` but that has some flaws.

- I can select the `ListViewItem`s(not necessary)
- `GridViewColumns` have headers(wasted space/ not necessary)
- `GridViewColumns` don’t support `Width = "*"` like a `Grid` and therefore doesn’t use all the available space

I could use a `Grid`, but than I would have to add `Grid.RowDefinitions` for every ViewModel and wouldn’t be possible to set the `Grid.Row` Property via Binding.

I also thought about using a `StackPanel`, but that doesn’t support Templating and I don’t know how to sync the `Width` for the first column.

So, does anybody know which `ItemControl` is best suited for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing it I would expect an ItemsControl with a data template to be a suitable solution.
You can use Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" on a parent element, in this case the ItemsControl, and then synchronize the width of the first column using SharedSizeGroup="somename".

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type MyItemType}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="column1" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>

                <!-- More stuff here -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why do I always forget that something like `ShardeSizeGroup` and `IsSharedSizeScope` exists? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a ListBox with a Grid as template like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeData}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data1}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```